# applet works on debian but not windows [mousePressed doesn't execute]

Tags: java, applet, mouseevent, cross-platform

I wrote a java applet and put it up on a server. 
When I visit the page from **debian/iceweasel** the thing **works perfectly.**
When I visit the same page from **windows/firefox** the applet loads and runs but the **code from the mousePressed and mouseEntered methods doesn't execute**. MouseClicked works fine, though.
Has anyone had that problem?
What other info do you need to tackle the problem? Do you need the code? The html of the page?

The applet is here:
http://whackamile.byethost3.com/
If you could go there and tell me your OS/browser combo and whether it works, that would be great! (the cursor is supposed to change when the mouse enters "mole" and it should be clickable)

Answer (score 0):

It was my custom cursor icon size/position. Windows, apparently, has a 32x32 limit.